# Openshift uploaded image via app get deleted after git push

Tags: cordova, ssh, openshift

I was building an app which allows user to upload an image for their recipe. So far i dont have a problem in uploading it to the server. The only problem i encounter is that whenever i git push my app (for php files) the images i uploaded were also deleted.

I also read some answers that it is about creating a symbolic link? Something like that.

1. I make a folder /.openshift/action-hooks/
2. Im gonna create a file pre-build there and will include the code that will create a symlink there.

Im a newbie in using openshift so please bear with me just needed a brief and clear explanation on how to create a persistent storage in openshift even after a git push.

Advanced thanks for those who will kindly answer my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["git push" deletes untracked remote files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339940/git-push-deletes-untracked-remote-files)

Comment: Already fixed the issue. I was mistakenly uploading it to the root folder which is also the folder which my source code resides. And already figured out on how to use action hook. Anyway thanks for the response.

Comment: @CharleneGonzales you should post an answer explaining what you did to solve the problem, and select that answer. Not only will this help you (your reputation score will increase) but it may help someone else out in the future who comes across the same problem.