# Git Losing Files After Merge

Tags: git

I'm very new to Git and I have run into a problem with an application that I have online. My application allows users to upload files to a public directory. When the files are uploaded, it creates a new directory and adds the files to it. When I make changes locally, and push the changes online, I lose everything that the user has uploaded. I am not sure how to get around this issue.

I tried adding the folder to the .gitignore file but that doesn't work. I also tried using git pull, but this will not pull down the app because it says that everything is already up to date. I also tried a git fetch but this didn't pull anything new either.

Not sure what to do.

Comment: have you consider saving the files in AWS S3 or something that are not on the server?

Comment: Seems a bit overkill don't you think?

Comment: What tech are you using

Comment: I'm using OpenShift.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339940/git-push-deletes-untracked-remote-files

Comment: I think the link above should work

Comment: I'm not really sure how to implement that process. Sending a request to OpenShift for some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using persistent storage.

```js
filePath = process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR + '/userImages/' + dir;
```